# AWS --Cloudformation --SubnetRouteTableAssociation --Failed to Stabilize in Time

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-vpc

I've got a stack that was building all the way down to the bottom but then for reasons I can't seem to figure out it started breaking in a weird spot which caused a CREATE_FAILED error.
  *The error code in question:* **A     AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation   SubnetRouteTableAssociationMain     Subnet route table association rtbassoc-894281e2 failed to stabilize in expected time**
  Now I find this really interesting because I had similar errors with this Subnet Association earlier in the build but it sometimes worked and sometimes failed. Here is the code base in question plus anything else that could conflict with this setup, what seems to be failing is the second to last block of code.

```
SocoDrIGW:
    Type: AWS::EC2::InternetGateway
    Properties: 
        Tags:
        - 
            Key: SOCODR
            Value: InternetGateway


RouteTableSocoDrMain:
    Type: AWS::EC2::RouteTable
    DependsOn: SocoDrVPC
    Properties:
                VpcId: 
                    Ref: SocoDrVPC

RouteDrMain:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Route
    DependsOn:
            - RouteTableSocoDrMain
            - SocoDrIGW
            - SocoDrSubnet01
    Properties:
        RouteTableId: 
            Ref: RouteTableSocoDrMain
        DestinationCidrBlock: 0.0.0.0/0
        GatewayId: 
            Ref: SocoDrIGW

#ERROR OCCURS HERE
SubnetRouteTableAssociationMain:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation
    Properties:
                SubnetId:
                        Ref: SocoDrSubnet01
                RouteTableId:
                        Ref: RouteTableSocoDrMain

SocoDrSubnet01:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Properties:
        AvailabilityZone: !Join [ '', [ !Ref 'AWS::Region', !Ref AvailabilityZones ] ]
        VpcId: 
                Ref: SocoDrVPC
        CidrBlock: 10.10.8.0/24

        Tags:
        - 
            Key: SOCODR
            Value: Subnet
```

Comment: I ran into this after mistakenly importing the same route table ID across different stacks - if you're using ImportValue then make sure to go back to your past stacks and see if you've made the mistake.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out what was wrong with it though. [According to the white pages:](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_Route_Tables.html) Each subnet in your VPC must be associated with a route table; the table controls the routing for the subnet. A subnet can only be associated with one route table at a time, but you can associate multiple subnets with the same route table.
 
  What I had configured was that the two subnet route table associations were cancelling eachother out because they both connected to the same subnet.